# Simple Hit Counter Servlet needing URL mapping for Reset Function

Tags: java, xml, servlets, servlet-3.0

I currently have a button that functions as a reset to my hit counter program. What I am trying to do is have /counter/reset function the same way if you type it into your URL. Below is my web.xml and my Java program:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Counter</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Counter</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Counter</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/counter/show</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/counter/display</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Counter extends HttpServlet{
    int counter = 0;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
    response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        if(Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("reset"))) {
            counter = 0; 
            response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() +
                request.getServletPath());
        } else {
            counter++;
            pw.println("<html><head/><body>");
            pw.println("<span>Hit Counter:" + counter + "</span>");

            pw.println("<a href=\"" + 
                getServletContext().getContextPath() + 
                request.getServletPath() + 
                "?reset=true" + "\">Reset</a>");
            pw.println("</body></html>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Counter.java and web.xml with,

Counter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.PrintWriter;    
import javax.servlet.ServletException;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

public class Counter extends HttpServlet {

```
 int counter = 0;
 @Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
response)throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    if(request.getServletPath().equals("/counter/reset")) 
    {
        counter = 0; 
        response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/counter/show");
    } else 
    {
        counter++;
        pw.println("<html><head/><body>");
        pw.println("<span>Hit Counter:" + counter + "</span>");

        pw.println("<a href=\"" + 
            getServletContext().getContextPath() + 
            "/counter/reset" + 
             "\">Reset</a>");


        pw.println("</body></html>");

     }
}
```

}

web.xml--

```
<web-app>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Counter</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>Counter</servlet-class>   
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Counter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/counter/show</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/counter/display</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/counter/reset</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I think, this is the solution of your query.

Comment: If you find the solution by any answer, you should accept that answer.